# Not Scroll to top when tapping on another tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey guys I've used the code bellow to scroll to top when tapping on a tabBar item. it's okay when you are in current view controller and works perfectly. but I want the table view not to scroll to top when tapping the viewController's tabBar item from another viewController. any ideas?

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: disable scrolling for your tableView @Omid Kia

Comment: @Ashish Bahi i cant. cell count is much more than screen size to fit without scrolling

Comment: Are you sure you are not reloading the table view when returning to the VC with the table view? That could cause the table view to be at the top.

Comment: @AleksanderAleksic it's required  for tableView to be reloaded. is there a way to reload tableView data without making it go to the top?

Comment: You can use as tabBarController.presentingViewController == YourViewController and make condition accordingly.